# Getting value from dynamically created pop up menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a menu that is dynamically created. When the user selects a value, I need to get that value and use it for a query statement. This is not a form, just a menu on the page.

I have:

```
<select name="topic" id="topic">
          <option value="optiont" selected="selected">Select topic...</option>
          <?php
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
          {
            echo "<option value=\"optiont$count\" name=\topic[]\">" . $row['topic'] . "</option>";
            $count++;
          }
          ?>
        </select>
```

I want to know which option is selected.  How can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**jquery:**

```
var selvalue = $("#topic option:selected").val();
$.get( "demo.php?value="+selvalue, function(data) {
  alert(data);
 });
```

**Demo.php:**

```
<?php
 $sel = $_GET['value'];
 // write your query here
?>
```

Comment: If this works, how do I use that value for a query within php?

Comment: remove the alert..make necessary changes in `demo.php` i.e using query.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value when you change the DDL:

```
$('#topic option').on("change", function () {
    var opt_ID = $(this).val();

//Do something here using opt_ID as the value e.g.
window.location = '/URL/file.php?' + opt_ID;
});
```

Comment: This allows you to get the value from the DDL then post it to a URL which would accept that value as a parameter.

Comment: What about if I need that value to insert into a SQL statement?

Comment: You could do it a couple of ways, either using Ajax as part of the change event, then the location redirect would go in the success action or you could check for a value on page load (at the top of the php file) then store it then... Have you had a go at anything like that yet?